# why can't I draw a square on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hey guy's I'm making a snake game in JS and right now all I'm trying to do is draw a snake in the center of the canvas. I've set the canvas dimensions to the board dimensions so everything scales right but nothing shows up. Any help would be appreciated:)

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimensions to board dimensions
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]


ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
ctx.fillRect(snake.x, snake.y, unit, unit);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="512"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `snake` is an array of objects. You either need to turn this into a single object for your code to work or use an index to select the object inside.

```
ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x-unit/2, snake[0].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
```

Also, note that in order to correctly centre your snake you need to subtract the `unit/2` from both `x` and `y` coordinates.

You can also remove the setting of the canvas dimensions within your code, as this is set when your define the `height` and `width` attributes on your `canvas` element.

See working example below:

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
  x: cvsW / 2,
  y: cvsH / 2
}];


ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x - unit / 2, snake[0].y - unit / 2, unit, unit);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

#canvas {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="512"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! also how'd you notice it wasn't centered? Did it look of on the canvas or did the code give it away

Comment: No worries. Both the code and the output on the canvas gave it away. It is easier to see that it isn't centered if you set the `unit` to a higher value such as `160`. But, if you didn't offset it by `unit/2` you are centering your box's top left corner in the center of the canvas, not the box's center in the middle of the canvas. That's why you need to provide this offset

Comment: Oh I see also I got a new problem, I wrapped those 2 lines that draw the square in a function and set that function to run every 70 ms, but nothing is being drawn. Ill edit my question so you can see.

Comment: @lolz Hi lolz, I think you accidently editted my answer instead of your question. Make sure when you edit your question you add a new code snippet under a heading such as **EDIT** so that future readers of this post will understand the original context of my answer. If your question is completely different you might benefit from opening a new question